# Type an object in flow with $Keys string literals as key but with different values

Tags: flowtype

I think this question is best illustrated with an example, let's say that we have an object in the following form:

```
type colorsType = $Keys<typeof colors>;

type ThemeColorTypes =
    {|
          +extraLight: string,
          +light: string,
          +normal: string,
          +dark: string,
          +extraDark: string
      |}

type theme = {
    +colors: { [colorsType]: ThemeColorTypes },
}
```

colors, in this case, is also an object literal with the names of the colors (excluding white) as key and the properties of ThemeColorTypes as values.

This works wonderful however for the color white I would like to add a more specific type. The key 'white' in colors should always be the value '"#ffffff"' (because it doesn't make sense to have a lighter/darker version of white).

My first attempt was:

```
type theme = {
        +colors: { 
          [colorsType]: ThemeColorTypes, 
          white: "#ffffff" 
        },
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. This leads to a lot of:

```
[Flow] Cannot get `theme.colors.primary.normal` because property `normal` is missing in `String` [1].
```

errors.

I could, of course, change the definition of ThemeColorTypes so that string is also a possible value but then I have to check if a color is a string or an object everytime I want to use normal/dark/extraDark/etc.

I would like for flow to know that when I access "white" it is always a string but for the other colors, it is an object of a specific shape.

I've googled around and it seems that they're some limitations around how this could be implemented in Flow but I couldn't find a very good answer on how this could be implemented.

So the more general question is, how can I type an object in flow using a combination of `$Keys` and literal keys with different definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to use [optional object properties](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties):

```
type theme = {
  +colors: {
       [colorsType]: ThemeColorTypes,
       white?: '#fff'
   },
}
```

so it's ok if `white` is missed, but if `white` exists it should be `#fff`.

You can also try with [spread operators](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#exact-object-types-):

```
type WhiteThemeColorType = { white: '#fff' };

type theme = {
  +colors: { [colorsType]: ThemeColorTypes, ...WhiteThemeColorType },
}
```

Or inline:

```
type theme = {
  +colors: {
     [colorsType]: ThemeColorTypes,
     ...{ white: '#fff' }
   }
}
```

[Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEDMBsHsHdQFAGNoDsDOAXUKYCd1QBeUAbwVFFgAsBLTAUwC5QByAYnC9YBoLQARpACGSANYtylSgwAemPMIAytAObVMLVr36VIajVp3TQqaHgC2wyEb4mAJsLwS2x6XIXCAIk5fbElAC+CMEImACeAA4MOND46AAqUTEkACQA0gzh6AA8EdHQ4LHxAHwA3AhhyaAJ1AwWDADCceZJ0YREumQAPl0mlADUHooq6pqgWHi0qKp2-SYD+mMsk9Ozff0DZpbWKwprc-ODjs57UzOHR0Pyij6nE-szG92hoPkxAOp0jLX1TS14NopMhUb7MNicbigQIVExVaJvOoNYhkfgDXDmdCSUAAbQxBCBAF0WL8Gs18ED0DxQAA6OlfegMUn-CnVQJ8UIoDDYcaYJHAqSUfFY1H9GiMrSQ8BuaRCUQuYU0uXiXTBQJAA). Hope it gives you some light to direction on how this issue could be solved.